# how to create own cache for file loading from disk to memory in c++ framwork?

Tags: c++, windows, caching, visual-c++

how to create own cache for file loading from disk to memory in c++ framwork,I do not want to use windows cache ,because some of case windows cache does not gives the good results ? 
Is there any plugin in c++ I can directly use for multiImport of file from disk to memory .

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you realize there are more than one cache involved in reading from a disk drive?

Answer (score 1):

**What do you mean by "windows cache does not gives the good results"? What version of Windows are we talking about here?**

The Windows file cache is actually quite efficient, but there are things a developer can do to their own data (if they fully control it) which can greatly improve the performance of file I/O. In particular, if you ensure your files are organized into multiples of 4096 bytes (aka 4k), you can make use of "overlapped" I/O  which avoids both blocking behavior and the need to do additional copies of memory data.

An example of this is the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the `WaveBankReader` class. The `xwbtool` command-line utility is used to pack a number of audio `.wav` files into a single file where each individual sound file is aligned to the 4096 boundary, a `xwb` file.

At runtime, the `xwb` reader then sets up the target memory and issues asynchronous reads. Ideally the application sets up a number of other reads, and then at some later time ensures that all async I/O is complete before using the data.

```
    struct handle_closer { void operator()(HANDLE h) { if (h) CloseHandle(h); } };

    typedef public std::unique_ptr<void, handle_closer> ScopedHandle;

    inline HANDLE safe_handle( HANDLE h ) { return (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ? 0 : h; }

    ScopedHandle m_event;
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
    m_event.reset( CreateEventEx( nullptr, nullptr, CREATE_EVENT_MANUAL_RESET, EVENT_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE ) );
#else
    m_event.reset( CreateEvent( nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr ) );
#endif

    if ( !m_event )
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( GetLastError() );
    }

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
    CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS params = { sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS), 0 };
    params.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
    params.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN;
    ScopedHandle hFile( safe_handle( CreateFile2( szFileName,
                                                  GENERIC_READ,
                                                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                                                  &params ) ) );
#else
    ScopedHandle hFile( safe_handle( CreateFileW( szFileName,
                                                  GENERIC_READ,
                                                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                                                  FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,
                                                  nullptr ) ) );
#endif

    if ( !hFile )
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( GetLastError() );
    }

    // Read and verify header
    OVERLAPPED request;
    memset( &request, 0, sizeof(request) );
    request.hEvent = m_event.get();

    bool wait = false;
    if( !ReadFile( hFile.get(), &m_header, sizeof( m_header ), nullptr, &request ) )
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        if ( error != ERROR_IO_PENDING )
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( error );
        wait = true;
    }

    DWORD bytes;
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
    BOOL result = GetOverlappedResultEx( hFile.get(), &request, &bytes, INFINITE, FALSE );
#else
    if ( wait  )
        (void)WaitForSingleObject( m_event.get(), INFINITE );

    BOOL result = GetOverlappedResult( hFile.get(), &request, &bytes, FALSE );
#endif

    if ( !result || ( bytes != sizeof( m_header ) ) )
    {
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( GetLastError() );
    }

    // ... code here to verify and parse header cut for readability ...

    m_waveData.reset( new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[ waveLen ] );
    if ( !m_waveData )
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    dest = m_waveData.get();

    memset( &m_request, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED) );
    m_request.Offset = m_header.Segments[HEADER::SEGIDX_ENTRYWAVEDATA].dwOffset;
    m_request.hEvent = m_event.get();

    if ( !ReadFile( hFile.get(), dest, waveLen, nullptr, &m_request ) )
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        if ( error != ERROR_IO_PENDING )
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( error );
    }
    else
    {
        m_prepared = true;
        memset( &m_request, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED) );
    }

    // ...
    // At some later point we need to check to see if the data is ready
    // or wait if the data is not yet ready
    if ( !m_prepared )
    {
        WaitForSingleObjectEx( m_request.hEvent, INFINITE, FALSE );
        m_prepared = true;
    }
```

This code makes use of the buffering hint `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` that the file will be read sequentially. You can also use the hint `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` if the file will really be access randomly instead, but it is more efficient if you can arrange your data for a sequential scan.

> The complexity here is that this code builds for Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.x, Windows 10, Xbox One, Windows phone 8, Windows 8 Store, and universal Windows apps. Namely I'm using the improved `GetOverlappedResultEx` on Windows 8 or later, but have to emulate it on older versions of the OS with `WaitForSingleObject` and `GetOverlappedResult`.

Having a few dozen outstanding read-requests of a reasonable size can also help optimize disk seek behavior but it is important not to flood the system with lots of small requests. Generally prefer to make read requests of 32k or greater at a time.

If you want to bypass the file cache for some reason (say you are doing streaming of audio and don't want any extra copies of it in memory anywhere because you know the data will only get used once before you read it again) you can use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`--be sure you aren't opening another handle to the same file without this flag or it will get buffered anyhow:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
        CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS params2 = { sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS), 0 };
        params2.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
        params2.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING;
        m_async = CreateFile2( szFileName,
                               GENERIC_READ,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               &params2 );
#else
        m_async = CreateFileW( szFileName,
                               GENERIC_READ,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ,
                               nullptr,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
                               nullptr );
#endif
```

As with all optimizations, be sure to profile both with and without `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` under real world loads to make sure you aren't actually making things slower by using it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining got an idea , For me If the internal cache is already there but that cache is not getting used results loading the file from windows cache is hapenning second time.